# Calculate NTFS and FAT file sytem size in Windows

Tags: c++, file, winapi, size, system

Does anybody know how to calculate the amount of space occupied by the file system alone?

I am trying to calculate how much space files and directories occupy in a disk without iterating thru the entire disk.

this is a sample in C++:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER freeBytesAvailable, totalNumberOfBytes, totalNumberOfFreeBytes;
GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(NULL, &freeBytesAvailable, &totalNumberOfBytes, &totalNumberOfFreeBytes);
mCurrentProgress = 0;
mTotalProgress = totalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart - totalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart;
```

But the problem is that I need to exclude the size of the file system but I have no idea if it is possible or if there is an API to get this info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. I don't see many real world use cases for such a feature, either.

Comment: Please define "size of the file system."  Do you count only the MFT, directory indexes, etc. or is it something else?  What about the unused space in the last cluster of most files?  Do you count that against the file or the  file system?  Depending on how you define it, it may be impossible, as dauphic pointed out.

Comment: We are actually writing a functionality that will investigate all user files in a disk and need to provide progress info for the operation as it can be very lengthy. 

We can't afford iterate thru the entire disk(folder and files) first just to calculate the size of the data. It is too time consuming... 

The code above doesn't exclude any file system which causes the progress, specially on NTFS to be very far from real. 

The close we can get to the real amount space occupied by all of the user data files the better.

Comment: "size of the file system" - anything that is used by the system to manage the files on the disk (MFT, directory indexes, etc).

"unused space in the last cluster of most files" - it is ok to ignore them for now.

Or if you have any other suggestions on how to calculate feel free to post!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make sense. On NTFS, small files are stored *in* the directory. I mean literally, they're inlined. The same sector that holds the filename also holds the file contents. Therefore, you can't count that sector as either "used for files" or "used for file system overhead".